# Get words which contains space in c

Tags: c

I need to get words from user which contains space as I expressed at title with struct statement.

For example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct knowledge
{
   char name[30];
}person;


int main()
{
   scanf("%s",person.name);
   printf("\n\n%s",person.name);
}
```

When I run this program and enter a sentence like "sentence" there is no problem. It show me again "sentence".
However, when I enter "sentence aaa" it shows me just first word ("sentence"). What is the matter here? Why it doesn't show me all ("sentence aaa") I entered?

Comment: @Leushenko well, not quite. Similar, but not a dupe, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `scanf()` use

```
fgets(person.name,sizeof(person.name),stdin);
```

It is always a bad idea to use `scanf()` to read strings. The best option is to use `fgets()` using which you avoid buffer overflows.

PS: `fgets()` comes with a newline character

Comment: You're very right, but instead of _only_ instructing someone to use some alternative, you may want to explain  the reason also. Just thought of mentioning. :-)

Comment: @NatashaDutta I have explained why and how to use fgets

Comment: That is not required, you see. Point them to the man page, let them read and come back if they have any doubt. What I was asking is to tell them why **not to** use something. That makes more sense, IMO. Anyways, it's just a suggestion, my own point of view. Peace. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`%s` format specifier stops *scanning* on encountering either whitespace or end of stream. hence, you cannot input a "sentence" with `space` using `scanf()` and `%s`.

To *scan* a "whole line" with space, you need to use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets), instead.